# Transform dataframe based on columns and rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

| CustomerNr | Target | Source | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | A | C | 0.2 |
| 1004 | D | np.nan | 0.3 |
| 1005 | C | D | 0.4 |
| 1010 | A | D | 0.5 |

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1001, 'A','C',0.2], [1004, 'D',np.nan,0.3],[1005, 'C','D',0.4], 
                   [1010, 'A','D',0.5]], columns=['CustomerNr','Target','Source','Percentage'])
```

to this one (any ideas how to formulate the title for this problem by the way)

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['1001 Target' , 'A',0.2],
                   ['1001 Source' , 'C',0.2], 
                   ['1004 Target', 'D',0.3],
                   ['1004 Source', np.nan,0.3],
                   ['1005 Target', 'C',0.4],
                   ['1005 Source', 'D',0.4],
                   ['10010 Target', 'A',0.5],
                   ['10010 Source', 'D',0.5],
                  ], columns=['CustomerNr Scope','Value','Percentage'])
```

| CustomerNr Scope | Value | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 Target | A | 0.2 |
| 1001 Source | C | 0.2 |
| 1004 Target | D | 0.3 |
| 1004 Source | NaN | 0.3 |
| 1005 Target | C | 0.4 |
| 1005 Source | D | 0.4 |
| 10010 Target | A | 0.5 |
| 10010 Source | D | 0.5 |

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas `stack` to achieve this:

```
(df.set_index(["CustomerNr", "Percentage"])
         .rename_axis("Scope", axis=1)
         .stack(dropna=False)
         .rename("Value")
         .reset_index()
         .assign(CustomerNrScope=lambda df: df[["CustomerNr", "Scope"]].astype(str).apply(" ".join, axis=1)))
```

---

Or concatenate the tables for source and target:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df[["CustomerNr", tscol, "Percentage"]]
               .rename(columns={tscol: "Value"})
               .assign(Scope=tscol)
           for tscol in ["Target", "Source"]])
df_new["CustomerNr Scope"] = df_new.CustomerNr.astype(str) + " " + df_new.Scope


# result
   CustomerNr Value  Percentage   Scope CustomerNr Scope
0        1001     A         0.2  Target      1001 Target
1        1004     D         0.3  Target      1004 Target
2        1005     C         0.4  Target      1005 Target
3        1010     A         0.5  Target      1010 Target
0        1001     C         0.2  Source      1001 Source
1        1004   NaN         0.3  Source      1004 Source
2        1005     D         0.4  Source      1005 Source
3        1010     D         0.5  Source      1010 Source
```

---

Or (building on Zephyrus' answer) use melt with `Percentage` as additional `id_var` to get the the desired table right away (assuming that `Percentage` uniquely depends on `CustomerNr`):

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['CustomerNr', "Percentage"],
        value_vars=['Target', 'Source'],
        var_name='Scope')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas melt to unpivot your dataframe:

```
df_melted =  pd.melt(df, id_vars=['CustomerNr'], value_vars=['Target', 'Source'], var_name='Scope')
```

This doesn't include the `'Percentage'` column, but you can merge that back into the new dataframe:

```
df_melted = df_melted.merge(df[[ 'CustomerNr', 'Percentage']], left_on='CustomerNr', right_on='CustomerNr' )

If you want your `'CustomerNr'` column and `'Scope`' column together you can easily add them together to one column.
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", encoding='utf-8')
df
```

```
CustomerNr  Target  Source  Percentage
0   1001    A         C         0.2
1   1004    D         np.nan    0.3
2   1005    C         D         0.4
3   1010    A         D         0.5
```

**Solution**

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_indx = len(df)
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    
    print(new_indx,"  ", ind)
    new_df.at[ind, "CustomerNrScoope"] = str(row['CustomerNr'])+'Target'
    new_df.at[ind,'Value'] = row['Target']
    new_df.at[ind, 'Percentage'] = row['Percentage']
    
    new_df.at[new_indx,"CustomerNrScoope"] = str(row['CustomerNr'])+'Source'
    new_df.at[new_indx,'Value'] = row['Source']
    new_df.at[new_indx,'Percentage'] = row['Percentage']
    new_indx = new_indx +1

new_df
```

**Output**

```
CustomerNrScoope    Value   Percentage
0   1001Target        A        0.2
4   1001Source        C        0.2
1   1004Target        D        0.3
5   1004Source        np.nan    0.3
2   1005Target        C        0.4
6   1005Source        D        0.4
3   1010Target        A        0.5
7   1010Source        D        0.5
```